# Export serialized array in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to serialize an array in bash and then export it:

```
function serialize
{
    for i in ${1[@]}; do
      ret+=$i" "
    done
    return ${ret::-1}
}

MEASUREMENT_OUTPUT_FILES=( t1DQ.txt t1CS.txt t2RXe.txt t2e.txt )
export MEASUREMENT_OUTPUT_FILES=${serialize MEASUREMENT_OUTPUT_FILES[@]}
```

The code produces the following error:

> MEASUREMENT_OUTPUT_FILES=${serialize MEASUREMENT_OUTPUT_FILES[@]}: bad
>   substitution

Any ideas what the correct syntax (error in the last line starting with export) would be?

Comment: That's not a safe serialization form for an array. Array elements (and filenames) are perfectly legal to contain spaces.

Comment: Also, if you *did* want to use that form, you could just use `string=${array[*]}`.

Comment: (By the way -- the `function` keyword here is a ksh-ism that isn't compatible with POSIX sh; bash supports it for compatibility, but the preferred syntax is the POSIX-compliant one, `serialize() {` with no `function` preceding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
export MEASUREMENT_OUTPUT_FILES=$(serialize "${MEASUREMENT_OUTPUT_FILES[@]}")
```

(where `$(...)` is a notation for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)).

That said, your command is actually equivalent to

```
export MEASUREMENT_OUTPUT_FILES="${MEASUREMENT_OUTPUT_FILES[*]}"
```

so you don't need the `serialize` function unless you want to improve your serialization logic. (Which you should consider doing, IMHO: just joining with a space is error-prone, because what if one of the arguments includes a space?)

**Edited to add:** Also, I don't know how we all missed this before, but this:

```
    return ${ret::-1}
```

actually needs to be this:

```
    echo "${ret::-1}"
```

or this:

```
    printf %s "${ret::-1}"
```

since `return` is for setting the *exit status* of a function, which must be an integer. (It's intended for indicating success, zero, vs. failure, nonzero, though some commands assign special meanings to multiple nonzero values.) What you want is for your function to "print" the files, so you can capture them.

Comment: Why call `serialize` or any other function to concatenate array elements with spaces? `${MEASUREMENT_OUTPUT_FILES[*]}` will do, as will `printf -v output_string '%s ' "${MEASUREMENT_OUTPUT_FILES[@]}"` if one *doesn't* trust the value of `IFS`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I noticed that, too (thanks to your first comment to the OP), and was updating my answer just as you were commenting on it. :-)

Comment: Even if you don't trust `IFS`, you can override it in a function; `serialize M a b c` with `serialize () { var=$1; shift; local IFS=" "; printf -v "$var" '%s' "$*"; }` would set `M="a b c"` regardless of the global value of `IFS`.

Answer (score 1):

bash has built-in variable serialization into bash-code using `declare -p`, and `eval` de-serializes, including arrays.

For this array:

```
a=("a b" "c'd")
```

serialize a into A

```
A=$(declare -p a)
echo "$A"
declare -a a=([0]="a b" [1]="c'd")
```

to de-serialize:

```
eval "$A"
```

to de-serialize into a different array name b

```
eval "declare -a b=${A#*=}"
```